# perfect foward a parameter pack: convert args without expansion?

Tags: c++, c++11, functional-programming, perfect-forwarding

In unit tests, I'm trying to achieve a more functional code and to simplify a class of function calls like:

```
std::wstring widestr = std::wstring(o.Descr.begin(), o.Descr.end()); //o.Descr is string
wchar_t message[100];
swprintf(message, 100, L"size: %d", size);
Logger::WriteMessage(message);
```

into:

```
Logger::WriteMessage(Message(L"string: %d", widestr.c_str()));
```

using:

```
template<typename... T>
wchar_t* Message(T &&... args)
{
    wchar_t message[100];
    swprintf(message, 100, forward<T>(args)...);
    return message;
}
```

But the output is different:

[image: Bad output]

instead of

[image: The output I want]

**1**. Am I doing the right thing in the first place ? What do I miss ?

**2**. Ideally I would like to write something like (c#):

```
$"size:{size}".ToLogMessage();
```

I think I cannot in c++{11,14,17}. Do you confirm ?

[`Logger::WriteMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-cppunittestframework?view=vs-2015#BKMK_Write_Message) is part of *Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework* and I can't change it.

Comment: are you on windows aka visual c++? if its the case which version ?

Comment: Your attempt returns a dangling pointer anyway.

Comment: Right. I corrected the question.

Comment: Are you reluctant to use `std::w?string`?

Comment: @UmNyobe VC++2017 version 15.9 v14.16

Comment: @YSC no; I'm actually using `string` that I pass into `wchar_t`. However, I think I could use a stream to pass into the MSFT `Logger::WriteMessage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you didn't expand the pack:

```
template <typename... T>
wchar_t* Message(T &&... args)
{
    wchar_t message[100];
    swprintf(message, 100, forward<T>(args)...);
    return message;
}
```

However, you're also returning a dangling pointer, and that's a big problem.

Ultimately, if `Logger::WriteMessage` *must* accept a pointer, you're going to have to wrap all three lines inside the utility. Like maybe:

```
template <typename... T>
void WriteLogMessage(T &&... args)
{
    wchar_t message[100];
    swprintf(message, 100, forward<T>(args)...);
    Logger::WriteMessage(message);
}
```

then just:

```
WriteLogMessage(L"size: %d", size));
```

Now I'll ask you to consider whether `Logger::WriteMessage` should just be doing all this itself in the first place.

Once you've got that going, you can think about switching from `swprintf` to something more C++-like so that you do not need to rely on some arbitrary maximum buffer size. However, arsing about with stringstreams and strings is not exactly the most efficient thing in the world, so you could also consider doing `swprintf` twice: once with a `nullptr` output just to get the resulting string size, then again to actually put it into a correctly sized `wchar_t` array…

…except unfortunately this is only possible with `snprintf`; for wide strings you'd have to make repeated attempts with increasingly large buffers until the return value indicates that the buffer you provided was finally large enough. Ugh.

Comment: Indeed, but I'm using `using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;` which does not this work.

Comment: @Soleil Then `WriteLogMessage` is probably your best bet.

Comment: It might be better to use `std::size(message)` than repeat the magic `100`. Nor am I conviced of the Merits of forwarding to a vararg-function (in contrast to variadic template).

Comment: @Deduplicator `std::size` is a good idea. A variadic template is fine but.. then what? You're back to stringstream and loads of copies/allocations, unless you can bring in Boost.Format or somesuch.